# Oracle 12.1 JSON_TABLE query fails during fetching rows

Tags: json, oracle12c, json-query

Oracle database 12.1

I have a table with a 2Gb json clob column (column name is jsonfile). The JSON clob loaded from file contains 2.530.000 records (viewed with Dadroit json viewer).
I want to load all the columns into a new table using json_table query. The json_table query fails with:

> ORA-40441: JSON-syntaksfejl
> 40441. 00000 -  "JSON syntax error"
> *Cause:    The provided JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) data had invalid
> syntax and could not be parsed.
> *Action:   Provide JSON data with the correct syntax.

And loads 2.490.000 out of the 2.530.000 records

example for 2 records from the json clob column jsonfile:

```
{"adgangsadresser": [
{
    "status": 1,
    "kilde": 5,
    "oprettet": "2013-06-21T09:46:52.617",
    "ændret": "2018-10-03T11:17:17.756",
    "ikrafttrædelsesdato": "2013-06-21T09:46:52.617",
    "kommunekode": "0253",
    "vejkode": "4651",
    "husnr": "40",
    "postnr": "4030",
    "etrs89koordinat_øst": 701554.33,
    "etrs89koordinat_nord": 6166158.62,
    "esrejendomsnr": "81",
    "nøjagtighed": "A",
    "adressepunktændringsdato": "2016-10-31T00:00:00.000",
    "højde": 35.3,
    "supplerendebynavn_dagi_id": null,
    "id": "d43e667f-10b9-4f5f-881f-bcd3898f3892",
    "supplerendebynavn": null,
    "ejerlavkode": 41251,
    "matrikelnr": "10am",
    "husnummerkilde": 1,
    "tekniskstandard": "TK",
    "tekstretning": 231,
    "esdhreference": null,
    "journalnummer": null,
    "adgangspunktid": "aa4ef631-52d8-4848-808f-607eb0ab5709",
    "vejpunkt_id": "20cf16b2-af45-11e7-847e-066cff24d637",
    "navngivenvej_id": "484312cd-529e-48c8-aaaf-d88ff71fc378"
}
{
    "status": 1,
    "kilde": 5,
    "oprettet": "2018-12-05T13:32:05.651",
    "ændret": "2019-04-02T15:17:33.831",
    "ikrafttrædelsesdato": "2018-12-05T13:32:05.651",
    "kommunekode": "0330",
    "vejkode": "1433",
    "husnr": "18B",
    "postnr": "4200",
    "etrs89koordinat_øst": 648401.776803554,
    "etrs89koordinat_nord": 6142162.98432597,
    "esrejendomsnr": "27367",
    "nøjagtighed": "A",
    "adressepunktændringsdato": "2019-04-02T15:17:33.831",
    "højde": 33,
    "supplerendebynavn_dagi_id": null,
    "id": "d43e0a22-fda7-4fe5-ae97-5ca20c9939ef",
    "supplerendebynavn": null,
    "ejerlavkode": 2001452,
    "matrikelnr": "24a",
    "husnummerkilde": null,
    "tekniskstandard": "UF",
    "tekstretning": 247.24,
    "esdhreference": null,
    "journalnummer": null,
    "adgangspunktid": "f8a95419-65b6-43f7-b195-1431d0b54f85",
    "vejpunkt_id": "85c73103-e022-4b97-a278-4f7b214962c1",
    "navngivenvej_id": "e2cf6c95-4ff8-4a58-89b7-c723c0638d13"
}]
}
```

My insert code:

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON


declare

cursor c1 is
SELECT STATUS, SOURCE, CREATED, CHANGED, INFORCE,
       MUNICIPALITY_CODE, STREET_CODE, STREET_NO, ZIP_CODE, X_COORDINATE, Y_COORDINATE, 
       PROPERTY_ID, ACCURACY, ADDRESS_CHANGE_DATE, ELEVATION, ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME_ID,
       ID_1, ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME, CADASTRE_ID, STREET_NO_SOURCE, TECHNICAL_STANDARD, TEXT_DIRECTION,
       ESDHREFERENCE, JOURNAL_NUMBER, NAMED_STREET_ID,
       ACCESS_POINT_ID, STREET_POINT_ID
  FROM json_access_addresses,   
  JSON_TABLE(jsonfile, '$.adgangsadresser[*]' 
              COLUMNS (
                STATUS      NUMBER PATH '$.status',  
                SOURCE VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.kilde',
                CREATED VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.oprettet',
                CHANGED VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.aendret',
                INFORCE VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.ikrafttraedelsesdato',
                MUNICIPALITY_CODE VARCHAR2(4) PATH '$.kommunekode',
                STREET_CODE VARCHAR2(4) PATH '$.vejkode',
                STREET_NO VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.husnr',
                ZIP_CODE VARCHAR2(4) PATH '$.postnr',
                X_COORDINATE VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.etrs89koordinat_oest',
                Y_COORDINATE VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.etrs89koordinat_nord',
                PROPERTY_ID VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.esrejendomsnr',
                ACCURACY VARCHAR2(4) PATH '$.noejagtighed',
                ADDRESS_CHANGE_DATE VARCHAR2(32) PATH '$.adressepunktaendringsdato',
                ELEVATION      VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.hoejde',  
                ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME_ID VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.supplerendebynavn_dagi_id',
                ID_1 VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.id',
                ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(256) PATH '$.supplerendebynavn',
                CADASTRE_ID VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.matrikelnr',
                STREET_NO_SOURCE VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.husnummerkilde',
                TECHNICAL_STANDARD VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.tekniskstandard',
                TEXT_DIRECTION VARCHAR2(16) PATH '$.tekstretning',
                ESDHREFERENCE VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.esdhreference',
                JOURNAL_NUMBER VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.journalnummer',
                ACCESS_POINT_ID VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.adgangspunktid',
                STREET_POINT_ID VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.vejpunkt_id',
                NAMED_STREET_ID VARCHAR2(64) PATH '$.navngivenvej_id'
               )
            )
;            

cnt integer := 0;
last_id varchar2(64) := null;

begin

delete from dawa_access_addresses;

for rec in c1 loop
  begin
    begin
      insert into dawa_access_addresses(STATUS, SOURCE, CREATED, CHANGED, INFORCE, MUNICIPALITY_CODE, STREET_CODE, STREET_NO, ZIP_CODE, X_COORDINATE, Y_COORDINATE, PROPERTY_ID, ACCURACY, ADDRESS_CHANGE_DATE, ELEVATION, ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME_ID, ID, ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME, CADASTRE_ID, STREET_NO_SOURCE, TECHNICAL_STANDARD, TEXT_DIRECTION, ESDHREFERENCE, JOURNAL_NUMBER, ACCESS_POINT_ID, STREET_POINT_ID, NAMED_STREET_ID)
      values(rec.STATUS, rec.SOURCE, rec.CREATED, rec.CHANGED, rec.INFORCE, rec.MUNICIPALITY_CODE, rec.STREET_CODE, rec.STREET_NO, rec.ZIP_CODE, rec.X_COORDINATE, rec.Y_COORDINATE, rec.PROPERTY_ID, rec.ACCURACY, rec.ADDRESS_CHANGE_DATE, rec.ELEVATION, rec.ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME_ID, rec.ID_1, rec.ADDITIONAL_CITY_NAME, rec.CADASTRE_ID, rec.STREET_NO_SOURCE, rec.TECHNICAL_STANDARD, rec.TEXT_DIRECTION, rec.ESDHREFERENCE, rec.JOURNAL_NUMBER, rec.ACCESS_POINT_ID, rec.STREET_POINT_ID, rec.NAMED_STREET_ID);
    exception
      when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('insert failed for '|| rec.id_1 ||sqlerrm);
    end;  

    cnt := cnt + 1;
    last_id := rec.id_1;

    if mod(cnt, 10000) = 0 then
      commit;
    end if;
  exception
    when others then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('loop failed for '|| last_id ||sqlerrm);
  end;
end loop;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('count '|| cnt);

commit;

exception
  when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('count '|| cnt);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('proc failed for id '|| last_id ||' '|| sqlerrm);
    commit;
end;
/

commit;
```

What do I to load all the records?
I cant find the record(s) that fails

Comment: Do you have to do interim commits?  The easiest option would be to do a single `insert ... select` with DML error logging https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2  If you really need the interim commits, you'd need to parse the JSON inside the loop and add an exception handler that catches errors and logs which rows fail to parse.  If you log the rows that you are able to successfully process, you could narrow the errors down to 40,000 potential rows and try to iteratively narrow down which rows are failing but that's not practical if this is an ongoing process.

Comment: Your JSON does not have a `,` comma between the objects in the array.

Comment: sorry, the json is comma separated, but I forgot this in the example

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is (with the key-value terms stripped out of the nested objects):

```json
{"adgangsadresser": [{}{}]}
```

It should have a comma delimiting the array items:

```json
{"adgangsadresser": [{},{}]}
```

---

In general for:

> I cant find the record(s) that fails

If it is one JSON file with 2.5 million array items and the initial step of parsing the JSON is failing then do a binary search:

1. Split the JSON array into two halves and try to load each half.
2. If a half fails then split the half into quarters and try each quarter of that half. If a half succeeds then you can ignore it as the error is not in those records.
3. If a quarter fails then split the quarter into eighths and try each eighths.
4. Keep splitting the failing fractions and repeating until you get to a single record.

Comment: sorry, the json is comma separated, but I forgot this in the example

Comment: How do I split a 2Gb json file?